# Is std::cout fully operating on the stack?

Tags: c++, heap-memory, cout, stack-memory

In C++, when I am using `std::cout` like that:

```
std::cout << "myString" << std::endl;
```

Is there anything that will be allocated on the **heap** by std::cout? Or will std::cout do everything on the **stack** (meaning that std::cout and its underlying functions won't do any `new/malloc/etc...`)?

I want to know if heavily using std::cout could cause some heap fragmentation

Comment: There is no guarantee that `operator<<(std::ostream&, T)` won't invoke `new`. This is obviously true for any user-defined `T`.

Comment: Why are you worried by heap fragmentation. Is there something else you are doing that makes this a big concern?

Comment: @LokiAstari I am just asking that out of curiosity.

Comment: Even more fundamentally, the standard doesn't talk about stack versus heap. It's entirely possible for a C++ implementation to not have a stack, by dynamically allocating everything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this specific example your code isn't causing any direct allocations on the heap.  However it's possible for the implementation of any method to use the heap for part of it's work.  This is perfectly fine so long as the method implementation properly cleans up after itself.

This logic applies to methods such as `operator<<(std::ostream&, T)`.

Comment: So it depends on the implementation of the stl. Isn't there anything that specifies how the memory should be handled by `std::cout` in the stl?

Comment: @olchauvin it depends on the implementation of `stl` and the implementation of `operator<<` for a given `T`.  I don't believe there is any specification available for how the implementation of `cout` manages memory.

Answer (score 5):

This completely depends on a certain implementation of the basic C++  libraries